# A cofinal function into a limit ordinal

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Let $\alpha$ be a limit ordinal. Let $f\colon\beta\to\alpha$ be a cofinal function, that is, a function so that $f(\beta)$ is unbounded in $\alpha$. That is, we have $(\forall \gamma < \alpha)(\exists \eta < \beta)(\gamma \leq f(\eta))$.

It is true that $\bigcup_{\eta < \beta} f(\eta) = \alpha$? If yes, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, yes. It is clear that $\bigcup_{\eta < \beta} f(\eta) \subseteq \alpha$.

Let $\gamma < \alpha$. Since $f$ is cofinal, let $\eta < \beta$ so that $\gamma \leq f(\eta)$. Then $\gamma < f(\eta) + 1$. Note that since $f(\eta) < \alpha$, $f(\eta) + 1 \leq \alpha$. Since $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, $f(\eta) + 1 \neq \alpha$, hence $f(\eta) + 1 < \alpha$. Again, since $f$ is cofinal, let $\xi < \beta$ so that $f(\eta) + 1 \leq f(\xi)$. Then
$$\gamma < f(\eta) + 1 \leq f(\xi).$$

Comment: I was wondering: is this implication reversible ?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\gamma<\alpha$. Since $ran(f)$ is unbounded in $\alpha$, we can find some $\hat{\gamma}\in\beta$ with $f(\hat{\gamma})>\gamma$ *(why could I write "$>$" instead of "$\ge$" here?)*. Now:

- How are $\gamma$ and $f(\hat{\gamma})$ related in terms of "$\in$" (rather than "$>$")?
- Why does this mean that $\bigcup_{\eta\in\beta}f(\eta)=\alpha$?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "related in terms of "$\in$" (rather than "$>$")". I thought **the** definition of $<$ between ordinals was exaclty $\in$.

Comment: @Jxt921 That's exactly what I meant. (The other key point being the fact that we can write "$>$" instead of "$\ge$" as per my italicized comment.)

Comment: Yeah, I think I got it. If you can, please, check my own answer (I started writing it before I saw yours, hence it is an answer and not a comment).

Comment: @Jxt921 Yup, it's correct.